# How to combine Clickhouse data by different periods depends on age of data?

Tags: time-series, clickhouse

I have big amount of data which collecting too fast, I started to feel lack of resources.

I am looking for something like AggregatingMergeTree, but I want to use different time periods for aggregations to decrease data density for older records

For example, I have some data each minute, I want:

1. last week store data each minute
2. last month store data aggregated by each hour
3. last 2 month store data aggregated by each half of day
4. last year store data aggregated by each day

Answer (score 0):

graphitemergetree https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/engines/table-engines/mergetree-family/graphitemergetree/

ttl group by -- https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues/14345

summingMT + clear column -- https://youtu.be/efRryvtKlq0?t=1756